# Angular, passing parameters in validation model driven

Tags: angularjs, validation

so here's my trouble, I'm validating Emails, and I'd like to be a bit permissive (depending on rather the email should be absolutely perfect or not), to do so I use a custom validator with a parameter withsuspicious (that'll trigger the exclusion of suspicious emails) so here's the code I have:

Component :

```
FormEmailAddress : FormGroup;
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }
ngOnInit(){
this.FormEmailAddress = this.fb.group({
        emailAddress: ['', Email.validateEmail]
  });
}
```

Validator :

```
static validateEmail(control, withsuspicious) {
        if (Validators.required(control)!== undefined && Validators.required(control)!== null) return null;
        return Email.checkValidity(control.value, withsuspicious)? null : { pattern: {invalid: true}}

    }
```

Email.checkValidity is just a function that validates email by returning true if good, false if not (with regexp and so on)

View

```
<form [formGroup]="FormEmailAddress" novalidate>
  <h4>Email Model Driven</h4>
  <input type="text" formControlName="emailAddress"/>
  <p>Email : {{FormEmailAddress.get('emailAddress').value}}</p>
  <p *ngIf="!FormEmailAddress.valid"> Wrong Email </p>
</form>
```

So I'd like to find a way to pass, as well as my "emailAddr" the parameter withsuspicious into my validator can you help me plz? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found how to do it, didn't change anything in view or validator, juste did this on component :

```
this.FormEmailAddress = this.fb.group({
            emailAddress: [''],
            withsuspicious: [true]
        }, {validator : this.validateEmail('emailAddress', 'withsuspicious')});
validateEmail(emailAddressKey, withsuspiciousKey){
        return(group : FormGroup) => {
            let emailInput = group.controls[emailAddressKey]
            let withsuspiciousInput : boolean = group.controls[withsuspiciousKey].value

            return Email.validateEmail(emailInput, withsuspiciousInput)
        }
    }
```